# Request into to Dataframe

Tags: python

please find below my request

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response=requests.get('https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/GeoArea/List')
headers={..........................................................
  }
```

## Extracts the response as html: html_doc

```
html_doc=response.text
```

## Create a BeautifulSoup object from the HTML: soup

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'lxml')
```

I found

```
<html><body><p>[{"geoAreaCode":"4","geoAreaName":"Afghanistan"},{"geoAreaCode":"248","geoAreaName":"Åland Islands"},{"geoAreaCode":"8","geoAreaName":"Albania"},{"geoAreaCode":"12","geoAreaName":"Algeria"}, ...]
```

How can I transform this result into to DataFrame?

Comment: are you trying to convert the JSON to a `Pandas` dataframe?

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'pandas' to do that https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: great just convert my data into Json and after DataFrame